# heroku run rake assets:precompile aborted because a file has a invalid UTF-8 byte sequence

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, precompile

Here's the exact message I got when I run git push heroku master

```
** Execute assets:precompile:primary
rake aborted!
/app/app/assets/images/images/index_solid.js has a invalid UTF-8 byte sequence
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/utils.rb:19:in `block (2 levels) in read_unicode'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/utils.rb:13:in `tap'
```

I accidentally put a js file that contains invalid utf-8 bytes in the images folder. But after I removed the file and remove all files in tmp/cache/assets, I still got the same error message. I tried both

```
git push heroku master  
heroku run rake assets:precompile --trace
```

but still received similar message. Thanks

Comment: have you tried `heroku run rake assets:clean`?

Comment: Yes I have, but still got the same error message

Answer (score 0):

You might still need to remove the .js file from your Git repository (this is different than just deleting it as a file).

Try running these set of commands from your console:

```
# Add files that might have been previously untracked
$ git add .

# Show the status
$ git status

# Remove deleted files from the git repository
# ... (if any deleted files show up in the 'unstaged changes' section)
$ for i in `git status | grep deleted | awk '{print $3}'`; do git rm $i; done

# Commit the changes
$ git commit -am "Deleted files"
```

This will help you remove deleted files from the git repository.

Before pushing to Heroku also make sure that you actually committed these changes to your `master` branch  or merged the branch you have been making them into your `master` branch.